# In real-time mode only allow one indicator trigger

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to implement an indicator trigger using a real-time candle. Unfortunately, the candle changes its status throughout the entire time unit. A long or short candle can result and now the indicator also reacts to different states of the candle.

How can I manage to allow a condition only once for a real-time candle and only when the indicator makes its decision?

I have already tried to specify alert.freq_once_per_bar in the alert() statement. Unfortunately, this instruction doesn't seem to work in realtime mode. At least not for me.

So how can I manage the real-time mode so that uncorrected conditions and alerts do not arise?

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing 'barstate.isconfirmed' within the condition. This approach allows the indicator to base the final decision on the candle close